# How to make TabWidget change Intents by using if statement

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-widget, tabwidget

Currently my code loads a `TabWidget` with 4 tabs. The first tab points to a disclaimer page which also takes in a username from a edittext box and stores it internally on the phone. I would like to have an if condition which checks to see if the username is stored on the phone and if it is then show the user a different "thank-you" page than the original disclaimer page. I believe my code isn't working because it's under the onCreate function and isn't refreshing...

```
    public class TabWidgetActivity extends TabActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab


    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)

    String username = null;  
    String pulledUsername = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString("username",username);

    // ******* MAIN PART I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH ********************************

    if (pulledUsername != null){
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
    }
    else {
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DisclaimerActivity.class);
    }

    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ MAIN PART I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_home))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ShowMapActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("Map",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_map))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SurveyActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("survey").setIndicator("Survey",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_web))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AnalysisActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("analysis").setIndicator("Analysis",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_analysis))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be a bit more clear about what "isn't working"?

Are you setting the username in the preferences within this Activity? If not then you should be using `getSharedPreferences()` as preferences are stored on a per activity basis.

when writing the username in the Disclaimer Activity

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("com.blah.application", MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString("username", username); 
  // Commit the edit!
  editor.apply();
```

When pulling the username in the other activity:

```
pulledUsername = getSharedPreferences("com.blah.application", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("username",null)
```

Comment: Sounds like this may be the problem... the way I have it written in the DisclaimerActivity is: 
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("username",username).commit();
How should I rewrite it for getSharedPreferences? Simply changing the name throws an error: The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) in the type ContextWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Definately was part of the problem, now the only issue is the onCreate never being called on again. I would like it to perform the check after a button click.

Comment: ^solved with startActivity(new Intent(DisclaimerActivity.this, TabWidgetActivity.class));